# C++ how to make a series of statements atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a program which have multiple threads running. Inside the main thread, a class variable maybe changed by operations from different threads. So I will like to make sure that within a series of steps involving the variable, no other threads may change the variable midway through that series of steps. E.g.

```
this->a = b / c;
if( this->a < d)
{
    this->e = 7;
}
```

In the above code, how do I make sure no interruptions from other thread occur E.g. thread 2

```
int j = 7 / 2
this->a *= j
```

Both threads tried to change the value of "a". How can I make sure that after `this->a = b / c`, the `if(this->a < d)` block will execute immediately before the `this->a *= j` statement has a chance to execute in thread 2? Thanks!

Comment: Use some synchronisation mechanism. Mutex, semaphore, memory barrier, ...

Comment: `std::atomic` was invented for that purpose.

Comment: How about a [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)?

Comment: I thought a mutex works if every thread is trying to access the same block of code, and you want to make sure only one thread can access the block of code any moment. In this case, the threads are trying to access the same variable, but not the same block of code.

Comment: Then you need (the same) mutex for all pieces of code which access those variables.

Comment: No, the mutex is there to stop the concurrent access to the same part of memory in that block of code, or any other block of code accessing that memory.

Comment: Also please show how you will code it, instead of just posting a comment here

Comment: @ablan some programmer dude posted the API documents that have the full reference guide and examples. It's important to learn how to read those, rather than needing people on here to specifically write your code.

Comment: Use a combination of std::mutex and std::scoped_lock. Like `std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx}`, where mtx is a mutex.  The scoped lock ensures you will be safe under exception conditions (like division by 0), the lock will always be destroyed and will unlock the mutex. Also : The use of 'this->` only adds noise to your code, it is almost never needed.

Comment: A mutex does 2 things: First it cause a barrier to reordering of operations by the compiler or cpu when you lock/unlock it. This protects a block of code form getting scrambled. Secondly it prevents two or more threads from acquiring the mutex. It's doesn't matter if it's from the same block of code of different blocks of code. It's the mutex that relevant. Same mutex used in different places means all those places will be run exclusively on one thread only.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think your answer is correct but the example shown in [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) is showing multiple threads trying to access the same block of code, instead of multiple threads trying to access the same variable

Comment: Mutexes can protect *any* block of code. It doesn't really matter if it's the same blocks in all threads, or completely different blocks (in completely different functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it seems your view of a mutex is that it serves to protect a *single* block of code, so that no two threads can execute it simultaneously.  But that is too narrow a view.

What a mutex really does is ensure that no two threads can have it locked simultaneously.  So you can have multiple blocks of code "protected" by the same mutex; then, whenever one thread is executing one of those blocks, no other thread can execute that block nor any of the other protected blocks.

This leads to the idiom of having a mutex that protects a variable (or set of variables); meaning, you set a rule for yourself that every block of code accessing those variables must be executed with the mutex locked.

A simple example (untested) could be:

```
class foo {
public:
    void f1();
    void f2();
private:
    int a, e;
    std::mutex m;
};

void foo::f1() {
    m.lock();
    this->a = b / c;
    if( this->a < d) {
        this->e = 7;
    }
    m.unlock();
}

void foo::f2() {
    m.lock();
    int j = 7 / 2;
    this->a *= j;
    m.unlock();
}
```

Now other threads can safely execute any combination of `f1` and `f2` in parallel without causing a data race or risking an inconsistent view of the data.

In practice, take advantage of RAII by using something like [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) instead:

```
void foo::f1() {
    std::scoped_lock sl(m);
    this->a = b / c;
    if( this->a < d) {
        this->e = 7;
    }
}
```

Among other benefits (that would become relevant in more complex code), it automatically unlocks the mutex for you at the end of the block, so you don't have to remember to do it manually.

Comment: Re, "a mutex that protects a...set of variables" You can never emphasize that enough. _Code_ is immutable. Code does not need to be protected. The reason we use a mutex is to prevent one thread from seeing variables in any temporarily inconsistent or invalid state that is due to the action of some other thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a `std::lock_guard` on a `std::mutex`. The point of the lock guard is to benefit from RAII so that the piece of code you lock is automatically released when the guard goes out of scope and is destroyed.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/n4oxWx6Me)

```cpp
#include <chrono>  // ms
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <future>  // async
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>  // lock_guard, sleep_for

std::mutex m{};

struct S {
    int a{};
    int e{};
    void work(int b, int c, int d) {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{m};
        fmt::print("Calling work with b={}, c={}, and d={}\n", b, c, d);
        a = b / c;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
        if (a < d) {
            e = 7;
        }
        fmt::print("S: a={}, e={}\n", a, e);
    }
};

int main() {
    S s{7, 15};
    auto fut1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&s]() { s.work(20, 30, 0); });
    auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&s]() { s.work(50, 6, 10); });
    fut1.get();
    fut2.get();
}

// Possible output:
//
//   Calling work with b=20, c=30, and d=0
//   S: a=0, e=15
//   Calling work with b=50, c=6, and d=10
//   S: a=8, e=7
```

And here's what can happen if you don't use any synchronization at all.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/5ETqj89d1)

```cpp
...
        //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{m};
...

// Possible output:
//
//   Calling work with b=20, c=30, and d=0
//   Calling work with b=50, c=6, and d=10
//   S: a=8, e=15
//   S: a=8, e=7
```

Comment: I assume you use `std::async(std::launch::async, [&s]() { s.work(20, 30, 0); })` instead of `std::async(std::launch::async, &S::work, s, 20, 30, 0);` to add clarity? Otherwise you could avoid the creation of a lambda object here.

Comment: @fabian To be honest, I wrote it like that because I've always been writing it like that before. But now that you mention it, I find your line better (probably not that clear, that's right). Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @rturrado Thanks for posting an example of the code! But the example is that of multiple threads accessing the same block of code instead of mutliple threads changing the same variable resulting in incorrect evaluation. I will edit my question to show this.

Comment: @ablan The idea is the same. If two threads execute the method `work`, one of them will be the first acquiring the mutex, and the other one will have to wait until the thread that got the mutex leaves `work`. Now check [this other example](https://godbolt.org/z/c9jcqKzWh). If two threads execute `block1` and `block2`, one of them will be the first acquiring the mutex, and the other one will have to wait until the thread that got the mutex leaves the function it is running.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to force `block1` to be executed before `block2` (although I don't know if that's what you pretend). In order to do that, you have other synchronization mechanisms, such as condition variables, semaphores, and so on, which would let you, for example, make the thread running `block2` wait until the thread running `block1` would have finished.